# list dependencies of all packages installed in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: dependencies

I have read that apt-cache depends  lists out the dependencies on package_name,however, is there a way I can list out all the dependencies of all the packages in a single command ( something like, apt-cache depends all ) ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`apt list --installed | xargs apt-cache showpkg > dependencies.txt`.  Beware it will take long and use all your cpu. I piped it to a file because it is a very long list.  The first part of the pipe provides all installed packages, the second part takes each one of them and looks for their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [blog post](http://www.ippatsuman.com/2014/08/03/visualizing-the-dependencies-of-installed-packages-on-debian/) trying to achieve what you asked for and explaining how to do it.

It is obviously not a trivial tree but more a galaxy of meshed nodes:

[image: example image of package dependency]